# Auto fill a form IE VBScripting

Tags: vbscript

Good evening All, I am having problem. I have a html page that I am testing automation on, in short, I am trying to auto fill the field with VB, the page has one field with a submit button.

Here is the name field code

```
<input ng-reflect-id="firstName" id="firstName" ng-reflect-type="text" type="text" ng-reflect-placeholder="Legal Name" placeholder="name" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
```

Here is the Submit button code

```
<button ng-reflect-type="submit" type="submit" ng-reflect-id="next_btn" id="next_btn" ng-reflect-class-name="btn mobile-primary margin-bottom-15" class="btn mobile-primary margin-bottom-15">
          Register
        </button>
```

and here is my Vb code..

```
    On Error Resume Next
Const PAGE_LOADED = 4
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Call objIE.Navigate("my page URL")
objIE.Visible = True
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop


objIE.Document.all.Item("firstName").Value = "Test"

call objIE.Document.all.Item("next_btn").click
Set objIE = Nothing
```

Can someone please let me know why this code is not working?

Comment: Please elaborate, _not working_ . Does the IE window open up?

Comment: Yes, it does open, the URL does come up as well but it does not auto fill the field

Comment: Any change if you use `objIE.Document.getElementById("firstName").Value = "Test"` instead of `objIE.Document.all.Item("firstName").Value = "Test"`?

Comment: No, I just tried that as well, No change.